# Autoincrement VersionCode with gradle extra properties is not working with Azure Git pipeline

Tags: android, git, azure, devops, pipeline

I'm doing automated build number generation via build.gradle using property file.
Changes on the property file is not being pushed in the Git Repository after the assembleRelease has been executed on Azure Devops

```
private Integer generateBuildNum() {

    File buildNumPropsFile = file('../app/src/main/assets/buildnum.properties')

    if (buildNumPropsFile.canRead()) {
        Properties buildNumProps = new Properties()

        buildNumProps.load(new FileInputStream(buildNumPropsFile))
        return buildNumProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger()
    }
    else {
        throw new GradleException("Could not read buildnum.properties!")
    }

    return null
}
```

```
private void increaseBuildNum() {

    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
        println taskGraph.hasTask(assembleRelease)

        if (taskGraph.hasTask(assembleRelease)) {
            /* when run release task */
            File buildNumPropsFile = file('../app/src/main/assets/buildnum.properties')

            if (buildNumPropsFile.canRead()) {
                Properties buildNumProps = new Properties()

                buildNumProps.load(new FileInputStream(buildNumPropsFile))

                def build = buildNumProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
                if(build != null) {
                    println "*********increaseBuildNum  build: "+build
                }
                buildNumProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = build.toString()
                buildNumProps.store(buildNumPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
                def buildUpdated = buildNumProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger()
            } else {
                throw new GradleException("Could not read buildnum.properties!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
         .....
        increaseBuildNum()
    }
```

The property file is working when the apk is built on local machine but not on Azure Pipeline. How can I update it on the Git Repo.